# Custom WinPE without extra languages

Tags: winpe

I maintain a custom [WinPE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/download-winpe--windows-pe?view=windows-11) that I periodically write to a bootable flash drive. However, no matter what I try, the .iso file that I make using [Deployment and Imaging Tools Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/makewinpemedia-command-line-options?view=windows-11) ends up containing many language directories on the root that clutter up the root of the flash drive. Is it possible to exclude them without having to delete them after writing the .iso to the flash drive? I only need US English. (Do I even need the en-us directory?)

**How it looks now:**

[image: How the flash drive looks now]

**How I want it to look:**

[image: How I'd like it to look]

Comment: “Do I even need the en-us directory?” -Yes; Providing the commands to create the ISO would be helpful. If you remove the packages, as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/customize-windows-re?view=windows-11#step-2-adding-languages), what happens?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I was sure that would work. However, after successfully calling `dism /remove-package...` 10 times per language, times 37 languages that I didn't want, and after successfully unmounting/committing it, the result still had all those language folders and files.

Comment: You ran `/Cleanup-Image /StartComponentCleanup` before you created the image?

Comment: Admittedly, I hadn't, but I did just now with no change in results.